# mysql crash error: page number in space is outside the tablespace bounds

Tags: mysql

mysql server crash error log is belows.   I'm trying to understand if this means the database .ibd file is too large or is it just corrupt?

```
Version: '5.5.30-cll'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL) by Atomicorp
InnoDB: Error: trying to access page number 117 in space 76859,
InnoDB: space name ./mydb/mytable.ibd,
InnoDB: which is outside the tablespace bounds.
InnoDB: Byte offset 0, len 8192, i/o type 10.
InnoDB: If you get this error at mysqld startup, please check that
InnoDB: your my.cnf matches the ibdata files that you have in the
InnoDB: MySQL server.
140314 23:47:35  InnoDB: Assertion failure in thread 140141628475136 in file fil0fil.c line 4493
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
```